# WCF service error 400 bad request

Tags: wcf, service, request

I've been searching this problem, and I found similar problems posted by other users, but everything I've tried doesn't work, The problem is that I'm using a WCF service hosted on IIS, and a client that try to upload a serialized image on a string, the size of the image is 9mb aprox, everythin else works fine, I can send data without problem except the image.

I have enabled tracelog and the error message says that the MaxReceivedMessageSize exceed

Here is my config on service:

```
<system.diagnostics>
<sources>
    <source name="System.ServiceModel"
        switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
        propagateActivity="true" >
        <listeners>
            <add name="xml"/>
        </listeners>
    </source>
    <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml"/>
        </listeners>
    </source>
    <source name="myUserTraceSource"
        switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing, All">
        <listeners>
            <add name="xml"/>
        </listeners>
    </source>
</sources>
<trace autoflush="true"  />
<sharedListeners>
  <add name="xml"
       type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
       initializeData="ErrorSvcLog.svclog" />
</sharedListeners>
</system.diagnostics>

<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IServicioSalud" closeTimeout="10:01:00" 
                maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" 
                maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" openTimeout="10:01:00"
                receiveTimeout="10:10:00" sendTimeout="10:01:00"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                    maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" 
                    maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="ServicioSalud">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="IServicioSalud" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
            <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="200000" />
        </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<diagnostics>
    <messageLogging
        logEntireMessage="true"
        logMalformedMessages="false"
        logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true"
        logMessagesAtTransportLevel="false"
        maxMessagesToLog="3000"
        maxSizeOfMessageToLog="2000"/>
</diagnostics>
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

And the client config

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding> 
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IServicioSalud" closeTimeout="10:01:00"
                openTimeout="10:01:00" receiveTimeout="10:10:00" sendTimeout="10:01:00"
                allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                useDefaultWebProxy="true" 
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
                <security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                        realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx:xxxx/wcfservicesalud/Service.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IServicioSalud"
            contract="IServicioSalud" name="BasicHttpBinding_IServicioSalud" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: You need to set the service endpoint to the binding configuration you defined (BasicHttpBinding_IServicioSalud) via the `bindingConfiguration` attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your config file you have not assigned the binding configuration you created, so the default values for `BasicHttpBinding` are being used.  You need to explicitly assign the binding you defined (BasicHttpBinding_IServicioSalud) to your endpoint, like this:

```
<endpoint address="" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IServicioSalud" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="IServicioSalud" />
```

Do this for your service config, as the service needs to be set to accept larger data.

Answer (score 0):

This is my version. Make sure you have have the **bindingConfiguration** specified in the service you want. In my case I have to specify the name *basicHttpBinding*.

```
<bindings>
   <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="basicHttpBinding" maxBufferSize="64000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="64000000" maxBufferPoolSize="64000000">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="64000000" maxStringContentLength="64000000" maxArrayLength="64000000" maxBytesPerRead="64000000" />
      <security mode="None"/>
    </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>


<services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="WS.Service1Behavior" name="WS.EasyStockWS">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBinding" contract="WS.IEasyStockWS">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
</services>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, the cause was the fact that in my request I had not set the content type.